# Angular - How to open a Bootstrap tab programmatically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-5

In a previous application, I needed to open a modal programmatically. This is a partial code of the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="messageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"></div>
```

This is the HTML link that is invoked from within the component to open the above modal:

```
<ng-container class="hidden">
   <a #openMessage id="open-message" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#messageModal">
   </a>
</ng-container>
```

And this is the component code used to invoke the above link:

```
@ViewChild('openMessage', { static: true })
   openMessage: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

private openModal() {
    let elementModal: HTMLElement = this.openMessage.nativeElement;
    elementModal.click();
}
```

I am trying to use the same process to open a Bootstrap tab. This is the target tab to be opened:

```
<a _ngcontent-ng-c4138276234="" role="tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" 
  class="nav-link ingredients active" href="#tab-10" aria-selected="true">
  <strong _ngcontent-ng-c4138276234="">Ingredients</strong>
</a>
```

This is the HTML link that is invoked from within the component to open the above tab:

```
<ng-container class="hidden">
  <a #openTab id="tabclicker"
    class="nav-link ingredients"
    role="tab"
    data-bs-toggle="tab"    
    data-target="#tab-10"
></a>
```

And this is the component function to invoke the opening of the tab:

```
@ViewChild('openTab', { static: true }) 
   openTab: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

private openTab() {
   let elementTab: HTMLElement = this.openTab.nativeElement;
    console.log('elementTab', elementTab);
   elementTab.click();
}
```

The case of opening the modal worked but in the case of the tab, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelectorAll' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a parent element with the class: "nav" to open/switch the tab.

```
<ng-container class="hidden">
  <div class="nav nav-tab">
    <a
      #openTab
      id="tabclicker"
      class="nav-link ingredients"
      role="tab"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#tab10"
    ></a>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lax81n?file=src%2Fmain.html)